# Agent Inheritance and Population Grouping

Tags: anylogic

I am digging deeper into Agent Inheritance and I am still at the exploration level so my question will not be specific to an example but rather conceptual.

My objective is to create a model with an Agent Type called **Machine**. However, there will be different types of Machines and some may have different statecharts or different parameters. So, initially I thought it would be a good idea to create an Agent Type called **Machine** and then, using Agent inheritance, create Agent Types that extend from it (e.g. *Machine 1*, *Machine 2*, etc.).

The result is that if I have one machine of each type, the **Machine** Agent Type population will be empty, while *Machine 1* and *Machine 2* each will have a population of 1. I understand AnyLogic is designed that way, but ideally, I would like to see the population of the **Machine** Agent Type with a population of 2, one of type *Machine 1* and the other of type *Machine 2*.

Agent inheritance might not be the answer, but I was hoping I could find a solution to this problem where I can have one main population with different sub-types.

You may ask why would that be needed. The answer is that all machines should have a similar behavior. Comparing this to DES, it's like having different Resources. All will have similar behavior (e.g. can be seize, released, attached, etc.) but each can be unique.

Your thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use agent inheritance, then you would need to have 2 different populations.  A population of type Machine will have agents of type Machine, not their child agent types.  I typically deal with this by having the populations for the child agents, and then storing all agents in a list (i.e., array list - allMachines).

You mention different state charts, which is a good reason to use inheritance.  Many people will try to inherit because one delay block takes X minutes, while another is Y.  In those cases, just parametrize your one agent type.  If the logical differences between these machines is small, I would consider just 1 class, with a few extra decides/branches to get the behavior you want.  It can sometimes be tricky in AL to have process blocks/visual elements in a parent connect to areas in a child - not impossible, but not as easy as pure Java code where you can override and call super.function().

Comment: Thank you Amy for your input. I thought of using a collection for all machines , but I was hoping to find a built-in solution for such a scenario. And yes, I did notice you cannot connect blocks/states from the parent Type to the child Type.

I think in summary, if the behavior is quite different, better opt for a list that combines all sub-types, otherwise stick to one population with optional states and parameters, would you agree?

Comment: Yes, I would agree.  By the way, you can connect process blocks at run time, but not necessarily easy.